# Custom SOAP Headers

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl

I am trying to convert a Java Web Service client to C#.  I have add a custom SoapHeader class to generate the necessary headers for authentication, but they are not being correctly formatted.  I am very new to C# Web Services, so any help is very appreciated.

Here is the format in which i need the headers:

```
  <soapenv:Header>  
     <USER soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xsi:type="xsd:string">xxx</USER>  
     <PASSWORD soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xsi:type="xsd:string">yyy</PASSWORD> 
  </soapenv:Header>
```

Here is what is being generated by the C# client:

```
  <soap:Header>
     <wsa:Action></wsa:Action>
     <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:ecb804bb-1104-4bfc-a8f8-c5f757d428fb</wsa:MessageID>
     <wsa:ReplyTo>
        <wsa:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:Address>
     </wsa:ReplyTo>
     <wsa:To>http://localhost:8081/emsapi/services/PSXAPI/r09_00_00</wsa:To>
     <wsse:Security>
        <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-4e8c838e-230c-4fb3-99b0-74f46f3652fa">
           <wsu:Created>2013-07-19T17:26:55Z</wsu:Created>
           <wsu:Expires>2013-07-19T17:31:55Z</wsu:Expires>
        </wsu:Timestamp>
     </wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
```

What do i need to put into my SoapHeader class to format them correctly?  For your reference, here is the header class:

```
public class AuthHeaders : SoapHeader {
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElement("USER")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapAttribute("USER")]
    public string USER;
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElement("PASSWORD")]
    public string PASSWORD;
}
```

Comment: you are looking for this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z52by6a(v=vs.80).aspx or this http://forums.asp.net/t/1137408.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, the first link pertains to web services and not the client.  I have tried the second link, but it errors out after modifying the app.config file.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in Microsoft.Web.Services3.dll

Additional information: WSE032: There was an error loading the microsoft.web.services3 configuration section.

Comment: Okay, i've fixed the app.config entry to compile correctly, but i now receive a socket exception on tcpMon.
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.axis.utils.tcpmon$Connection.run(tcpmon.java:1087)

Comment: don't know anything about java :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution came with the SoapExtension class and modifying the attributes as necessary.